# Scrape only returns the table header, is this the website's fault?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the data from this URL: https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp

However, the output of the code is only the table header. I couldn't find another URL to put in and when I searched for the number of tables within the site, it only returned one (the header). Is this a problem with the site or do I need to do something to get the table?

I tried searching for other URLs to fill in the search, but I couldn't find any.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp'

pd.read_html(url, decimal=',', thousands='.')[0]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `[0]` on the end of the function call?  Is this supposed to return only the first table?  Only the first **row** of the first table?

Comment: It was supposed to return only the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code of the page is really malformed, so I recommend to use `beautifulsoup` + `html5lib` parser to get the table data:

```py
from io import StringIO

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp"
table = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html5lib").table

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)), decimal=",", thousands=".")[0]
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
  Dias Corridos  DI x pré       
  Dias Corridos 252(2)(4) 360(1)
0             1     13.15   0.00
1             3     12.97  19.03
2             7     12.93  13.21
3             9     12.92  14.45
4            14     12.90  13.18
```